# Websites not loading. jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

This isn't exactly a programming question, but I think it will help Javascript developers.

I've been facing problems opening a few sites from any browser (particularly, the Gawker Media websites (Gizmodo, Lifehacker, Gawker...)
Only the top panel loads in Chrome and Firefox, and the page without images in Internet Explorer.

I took a look at the Chrome console at the page and there were errors like

`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

[image: Here's] a screenshot

Now from my searches I found that this is usually solved by adding certain lines to the webpage code, but obviously that's not the problem here.

Apologies if this question doesn't belong here, but would be great if someone could answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that something on your network channel (such as the HOSTS file or a firewall) is blocking access to the JavaScript files that define jQuery. Look at the Network tab and see if that file is failing to load.